# Calculation of electric potential in Geiger-Müller tube

Tags: electrostatics, potential

We are given a cylindrical rod with linear charge density $λ$, and a coaxial cylinder with linear charge density $-λ$, as shown in the picture.

[image]

We are to show that the potential difference between $r_a$ and $r_b$ is 
$$ΔV=2 k_e λ \ln\big( \frac{r_a}{r_b} \big).$$

We can easily calculate from Gauss' Law that the magnitude of the electric field at a distance $r$ from the axis of symmetry is $E=\frac{2 k_e λ}{r}.$ From the definition of potential difference we have
$$ΔV=- \int_{\vec{r_a}}^{\vec{r_b}} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}.$$
Now, the field points radially outward, and $d\vec{s}=-dr \hat{r}$, so $\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}=-Edr$. Therefore we should get
$$ΔV=- \int_{\vec{r_a}}^{\vec{r_b}} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}= \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \frac{2 k_e λ}{r} dr=2k_eλ\ln \big( \frac{r_b}{r_a}\big).$$ Why do I get the sign wrong?

Comment: But $\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}=-\frac{2 k_e λ}{r}dr$, so that was on purpose.

Comment: Why? Aren't they in opposite directions?

Comment: You're right. They are in opposite directions, but the sign is implemented in the $dr$.

Answer (score 1):

The misconception arose from the fact that $d\vec{s}$ was taken at a specific path (that is, the radial path from the outer cylinder to the rod). However, one need not take this specific path. $dr=ds \cos{θ}$, does not carry a sign, as the cosine takes care of that. What I meant by $\hat{r} \cdot d\vec{s}=-dr$ was $d\vec{s}\cdot\hat{r}=-ds$, and that is why I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$E=\frac{2 k_e λ}{r}$ is an electric field pointing radially outwards.

Now there are two equivalent ways to define the potential difference between two points.

---

The first definition is that the potential difference between two points is **minus** the work done by the **electric field** in taking unit positive charge from the first point to the second point.

Using this definition.

The work done by the electric field in moving unit positive a distance $dr$ radially outwards is $E\; dr =\dfrac{2 k_e λ}{r}\;dr$

So the total work done by the electric field in moving unit positive charge from $r_b$ to $r_a$ is

$\displaystyle \int_{r_b}^{r_a} \dfrac{2 k_e λ}{r} dr=2k_eλ\ln \big( \dfrac{r_a}{r_b}\big)$

and this is $- (V_a - V_b) = (V_b - V_a) = \Delta V$

---

The second definition is that the potential difference between two points is  the work done by an **external force** in taking unit positive charge from the first point to the second point.

Using this definition.

The work done by the external force in moving unit positive a distance $dr$ radially outwards is $-E\; dr =-\frac{2 k_e λ}{r}\;dr$

So the total work done by the external force in moving unit positive charge from $r_b$ to $r_a$ is

$\displaystyle \int_{r_b}^{r_a} -\dfrac{2 k_e λ}{r} dr=-2k_eλ\ln \big( \frac{r_a}{r_b}\big) = (V_a - V_b)$

$\Rightarrow 2k_eλ\ln \big( \frac{r_a}{r_b}\big) = (V_b - V_a) = \Delta V$

Comment: So I did get it wrong, my potential difference is negative!

Comment: @Valentina  As a result of your comment I have rewritten my answer.